# Removing my button and having JavaScript auto calculate

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is I cant seem to remove this button and have my price auto calculate.

I've tried many many ways and I just can't seem to figure it out.

```js
var current_division,
       desired_division;


function current1() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.CRANK1;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.CRANK2;
    return parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
}

function desiredd() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.DRANK1;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.DRANK2;
    return price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
    
}

function total() {
    if(isNaN(current1())) {
        current_division = 0;
    } else {
        current_division = current1();
    }   
    
    if(isNaN(desiredd())){
       desired_division = 0;   
    } else {
       desired_division = desiredd();
    }
    
    var totalPrice = current_division+desired_division;
    
    document.getElementById('prices').value = totalPrice;
}

document.getElementById('submit_button').addEventListener('click', function(){

    total();
})
```

```css
select:valid {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1px solid grey;
  text-align-last:left;
  
  
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:  #D3D3D3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 


    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 


    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(paper.gif);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 1px; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px; 

   
  }
  form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

   input {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<form name="priceCalc" action="">Current Division
    <br/>Rank:
    <select name="CRANK1">
        <option type="text" value="1">Bronze</option>
        <option type="text" value="2">Silver</option>
        <option type="text" value="3">Gold</option>
        <option type="text" value="4">Platinum</option>
        <option type="text" value="5">Diamond</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br/>Division:
    <select name="CRANK2">
        <option type="text" value="6">Division V</option>
        <option type="text" value="7">Division IV</option>
        <option type="text" value="8">Division III</option>
        <option type="text" value="9">Division II</option>
        <option type="text" value="10">Division I</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br/>Desired Division
    <br/>Rank:
    <select name="DRANK1" >
        <option type="text" value="1">Bronze</option>
        <option type="text" value="2">Silver</option>
        <option type="text" value="3">Gold</option>
        <option type="text" value="4">Platinum</option>
        <option type="text" value="5">Diamond</option>
    </select>
     <br>
     <br/>Division:
    <select name="DRANK2" >
        <option type="text" value="6">Division V</option>
        <option type="text" value="7">Division IV</option>
        <option type="text" value="8">Division III</option>
        <option type="text" value="9">Division II</option>
        <option type="text" value="10">Division I</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="prices">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Figure out pricing!" id="submit_button">
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: java has nothing to do with javascript. If you have no Java code involved, please remove the java tag !

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. Did you mean to tag Java?

Comment: Please don't post your working code to 3rd party sites and link to them in your question as those links can die over time and then your question becomes much more difficult for others to understand. Additionally, it's inconvenient for us to have to go to another site to understand what you are doing. Just include your code in a "code snippet", right here in your question.

Comment: FYI: Don't use self-terminating tag syntax (i.e. `<br />`). **[Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `change` event listener to each dropdown. Change the "name" fields on your `select` elements to `id` fields and grab them by ID using JS. Then, add an event listener which will run your `total()` function whenever your dropdown values are updated.

```
document.getElementById("CRANK1").addEventListener('change', total);
document.getElementById("CRANK2").addEventListener('change', total);
document.getElementById("DRANK1").addEventListener('change', total);
document.getElementById("DRANK2").addEventListener('change', total);
```

```js
var current_division,
       desired_division;


function current1() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.CRANK1;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.CRANK2;
    return parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
}

function desiredd() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.DRANK1;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.DRANK2;
    return price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
    
}

function total() {
    if(isNaN(current1())) {
        current_division = 0;
    } else {
        current_division = current1();
    }   
    
    if(isNaN(desiredd())){
       desired_division = 0;   
    } else {
       desired_division = desiredd();
    }
    
    var totalPrice = current_division+desired_division;
    
    document.getElementById('prices').value = totalPrice;
}

document.getElementById("CRANK1").addEventListener('change', total);
document.getElementById("CRANK2").addEventListener('change', total);
document.getElementById("DRANK1").addEventListener('change', total);
document.getElementById("DRANK2").addEventListener('change', total);
```

```css
select:valid {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1px solid grey;
  text-align-last:left;
  
  
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:  #D3D3D3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 


    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 


    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(paper.gif);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 1px; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px; 

   
  }
  form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

   input {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<form name="priceCalc" action="">Current Division
    <br/>Rank:
    <select id="CRANK1">
        <option type="text" value="1">Bronze</option>
        <option type="text" value="2">Silver</option>
        <option type="text" value="3">Gold</option>
        <option type="text" value="4">Platinum</option>
        <option type="text" value="5">Diamond</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br/>Division:
    <select id="CRANK2">
        <option type="text" value="6">Division V</option>
        <option type="text" value="7">Division IV</option>
        <option type="text" value="8">Division III</option>
        <option type="text" value="9">Division II</option>
        <option type="text" value="10">Division I</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br/>Desired Division
    <br/>Rank:
    <select id="DRANK1" >
        <option type="text" value="1">Bronze</option>
        <option type="text" value="2">Silver</option>
        <option type="text" value="3">Gold</option>
        <option type="text" value="4">Platinum</option>
        <option type="text" value="5">Diamond</option>
    </select>
     <br>
     <br/>Division:
    <select id="DRANK2" >
        <option type="text" value="6">Division V</option>
        <option type="text" value="7">Division IV</option>
        <option type="text" value="8">Division III</option>
        <option type="text" value="9">Division II</option>
        <option type="text" value="10">Division I</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="prices">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Figure out pricing!" id="submit_button">
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't post your working code to 3rd party sites and link to them in your answers as those links can die over time and then your answer becomes much more difficult for others to understand. Additionally, it's inconvenient for us to have to go to another site to understand what you are doing. Just include your code in a "code snippet", right here in your answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus My apologies. Thanks for migrating the jsfiddle to my answer. Will include my code snippets directly in my answers from now on.

Comment: Also, `onchange` is a DOM element property. `change` is the actual event name and that is what needs an event listener set up with `.addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding one event listener to each of the selects, you could add one event listener to the form. 
You add an id to the form:

```
<form id="myform" name="priceCalc" action="">Current Division
```

then you add the eventListener to it:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('change', function(){
total();
})
```

Here is a working example

```js
var current_division,
       desired_division;


function current1() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.CRANK1;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.CRANK2;
    return parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
}

function desiredd() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.DRANK1;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.DRANK2;
    return price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
    
}

function total() {
    if(isNaN(current1())) {
        current_division = 0;
    } else {
        current_division = current1();
    }   
    
    if(isNaN(desiredd())){
       desired_division = 0;   
    } else {
       desired_division = desiredd();
    }
    
    var totalPrice = current_division+desired_division;
    
    document.getElementById('prices').value = totalPrice;
}

document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('change', function(){

    total();
})
```

```css
select:valid {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1px solid grey;
  text-align-last:left;
  
  
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:  #D3D3D3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 


    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 


    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(paper.gif);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding: 1px; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px; 

   
  }
  form {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

   input {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" name="priceCalc" action="">Current Division
    <br/>Rank:
    <select name="CRANK1" id="CRANK1">
        <option type="text" value="1">Bronze</option>
        <option type="text" value="2">Silver</option>
        <option type="text" value="3">Gold</option>
        <option type="text" value="4">Platinum</option>
        <option type="text" value="5">Diamond</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br/>Division:
    <select name="CRANK2">
        <option type="text" value="6">Division V</option>
        <option type="text" value="7">Division IV</option>
        <option type="text" value="8">Division III</option>
        <option type="text" value="9">Division II</option>
        <option type="text" value="10">Division I</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br/>Desired Division
    <br/>Rank:
    <select name="DRANK1" >
        <option type="text" value="1">Bronze</option>
        <option type="text" value="2">Silver</option>
        <option type="text" value="3">Gold</option>
        <option type="text" value="4">Platinum</option>
        <option type="text" value="5">Diamond</option>
    </select>
     <br>
     <br/>Division:
    <select name="DRANK2" >
        <option type="text" value="6">Division V</option>
        <option type="text" value="7">Division IV</option>
        <option type="text" value="8">Division III</option>
        <option type="text" value="9">Division II</option>
        <option type="text" value="10">Division I</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="prices">
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Figure out pricing!" id="submit_button">
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't post your working code to 3rd party sites and link to them in your answers as those links can die over time and then your answer becomes much more difficult for others to understand. Additionally, it's inconvenient for us to have to go to another site to understand what you are doing. Just include your code in a "code snippet", right here in your answer.

Comment: `document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('change', function(){ total(); })` can just be: `document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('change', total)`

Comment: Yes, you could write it like that also, actually is much readable that way.

Comment: Didn't think about the linking to 3rd party sites problem. Will use 'code snippets' from now on.