# Dynamically change the variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Since I have couple of entries that needs to be divided with the number i provide (num1 variable), I find the difficulties to complete the task.

I want the loop to divide me and store value from each variable called listX with 34. There are 9 lists (each has different number) and i want each list to be divided with the number i provide, but to be divided first with 2, then with 3, then with 4, 5 ... up to the number i provide.

I figured out that it could be done best with objects, but I can't find the solution, since I'm not so experienced with this stuff. The ideal would be to get the objects like:

List1: 1st division: xxx

List1: 2nd division: xxx

List1: 34th division: xxx

...

List 8: 22nd division: xxx

...

List 9: 33rd divison: xxx
List 9: 34th division: xxx

**"xth division" should be linked with the number i provided in the num1 variable**

What I'm trying to get is something like this:

It asks me how many times i want my values to be divided, i type in 5. Then it asks me what are the values of my 9 inputs.

I declare to the first input 100. The result what I want should be:

100/1 = 1

100/2 = 50

100/3 = 33,33

100/4 = 25

100/5 = 20

Then I declare to the second input number 200. The result should be:

200/1 = 200

200/2 = 100

200/3 = 66,66

200/4 = 50

200/5 = 40

It goes all the way up until my last input...

What I'm trying to develop is D'Hondt method for seat allocations in the parliament that is being used for some countries.

Here is what I've got so far, but ofc, it is not working.

```js
var array1 = [];
var list = "list";

function someFunction() {
    var num1 = 34;
    for (var i = 1; i <= num1; ++i) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {

            array1[j] += document.getElementById(list + j).value / i;
            array1[j] += "<br/>";

        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = list + j;
}
```

```html
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="list1" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list2" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list3" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list4" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list5" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list6" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list7" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list8" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="list9" style="width:50px" onkeyup="someFunction()"></input></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Tip: `input` is a self closing tag, don't use `</input>`, just close it like: `<input type... />`

Comment: now, please, provide a working snippet, the one that is here have errors of undefined elements that impossibilitates us to test and identify possible errors. And if possible, clarify your question, it is very hard to understant the desired result.

Comment: What does ` loop to divide me and store each listX variable with the num1.` means??

Comment: @CalvinNunes IMHO don't recommend self-terminating syntax. XHTML is not widely used anymore and that syntax *will* lead to problems when used by inexperienced developers.

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee There is an input on the page, and the number i put there should be divided with 2, 3, 4, 5 etc, up to the number I want. That is 34. So, basically, if i type 150 in the "list1", i want that 150 to be divided with 2, 3, 4 and to end with the num1 variable (which is 34). Hope you understand me now. Thanks

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok... said that because StackOverflow snippet shows the `</input>` with a red color like an error, and show it with no problems when using `/>`

Comment: @CalvinNunes Self-terminating syntax is *legal* syntax (it's XHTML), but it adds no value to HTML and *will* confuse new developers. Since it adds no value, [it should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597).

Comment: slightly confusing what you are to achieve, please give sample input and expected output and values in the input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, but a couple of notes.

A couple of notes:

- The `input` element does not have a closing tag.
- `type="text` is the default for `input` elements, so you don't need
  to write it.
- Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY). Since all of your `input` elements need
  the same styling, just set up a single CSS rule to style them all the
  same way.
- Don't use inline HTML event handlers. Separate your JavaScript from
  your HTML and follow modern standards.

See the comments below for details.

```js
// Get the number to divide by (You can get this anyway you want. A prompt is show here.):
var num = +prompt("How many calculations per input would you like?");

// Get all the table inputs into an array
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td > input[id^='input']"));

// Loop over the input array...
inputs.forEach(function(input){
  // Set up an event handler for the input
  input.addEventListener("input", someFunction);
});

function someFunction(){
  var resultString = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    // Do the math and build up the string
    resultString += (this.value / (i + 1)) + "<br>"; 
  }
  
  // Update the output cell that corresponds to the input element with the results
  document.querySelector("#" + this.id.replace("input", "output")).innerHTML = resultString;
}
```

```css
td > input { width:50%; }
```

```html
<table id="inout">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="input1"></td>
    <td><input id="input2"></td>
    <td><input id="input3"></td>
    <td><input id="input4"></td>
    <td><input id="input5"></td>
    <td><input id="input6"><td>
    <td><input id="input7"></td>
    <td><input id="input8"></td>
    <td><input id="input9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="output1"></td>
    <td id="output2"></td>
    <td id="output3"></td>
    <td id="output4"></td>
    <td id="output5"></td>
    <td id="output6"><td>
    <td id="output7"></td>
    <td id="output8"></td>
    <td id="output9"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Seems like a cool idea, but not exactly what i want. Here, if i enter number 5 to divide by, and i want, for example, to divide 15 with 5, it gives me the result .2 and 3. The results i want is 15, 7.5, 5, 3.75, 3.

Comment: @Guev4ra Then what are the 9 inputs for? Why 9 of them? Are people supposed to type in them or are you using them so show the output?

Comment: @Guev4ra Also, your comment is confusing. How many numbers does the user input? 1 or 2?

Comment: Each input should have values assigned. While the values are being assigned, it should do the division.
So, Input1 should have 1 value and 34 (variable num1) outputs with divisions. Same goes with all other inputs.

Comment: @Guev4ra OK, take a moment and please try to clearly explain what you want. It makes sense to you, but not to us. You are showing 9 inputs. So the user comes along and puts, let's say `5` into the first input. What should happen then? Does something happen in the other 8 inputs automatically after the user enters into the first one?  Where does the output go? What, exactly should the output be? You're mentioning the number `34`. Where does that come in? Please edit your question to clarify all of this.

Comment: Sorry. First, user enters a number at prompt (lets say 5), and then enters for example 100 into first input, that number (100) should be divided with 1, then 100/2, then 100/3, then 100/4, and finally 100/5. When user enters at 2nd input, lets say 200, same principle applies. That 200 (value from input2) is going to be divided with 1, then 2, 3, 4 and again 5. Still, he enters 300 at input3, 300 is being divided with 1, 2, 3, 4 and finishes with 5. Same principle should be applied to all other inputs. 
The output should be stored for each input. So, output1 stores results from the input1 etc