# javascript else statement return true only when everything is filled in correctly

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have made a small form that checks whether everything has been filled in correctly. I use the `if...else` statement in my code to check the input.

In the console it returns `true` when it should return `false` because I have not entered anything in the input boxes. I want my `else` statement to return `true` only when everything is filled in correctly.

```js
function validate() {
  var fields = f1.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var attribute = [];
  for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if (fields[i].type != "submit") {
      attribute.push(fields[i].getAttribute('validate').split('|'));
    }
  }

  var name = document.f1.name.value;
  var namelength = document.f1.name.value.length;
  var status = false;
  var emptyName = attribute[0][0];

  // CHECK NAME
  
  if (emptyName == "empty-allowd") {
    emptyName = 0;
  }
  if (emptyName == "empty-not-allowd") {
    emptyName = 1;
  }
  if (emptyName == 0) {
    document.getElementById("namelocation").innerHTML = "ok";
    status = true;
  }
  if (emptyName == 1) {
    document.getElementById("namelocation").innerHTML = "Required.";
    status = false;
  }
  if (namelength > 0 && namelength < attribute[0][1]) {
    document.getElementById("namelocation").innerHTML = "Name not shorter than" + " " + attribute[0][1] + " " + "characters.";
    status = false;
  }
  if (namelength > attribute[0][2]) {
    document.getElementById("namelocation").innerHTML = "Name not longer than" + " " + attribute[0][2] + " " + "characters.";
    status = false;
  } else {
    status = true;
    console.log(status);
    alert(status);
  }

  return status;
}
```

```html
<form name="f1" action="" method="/" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" validate="empty-not-allowd|5|20" />
        <span id="namelocation" style="color:red"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="register" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes I have, it's after the last if statement ;)

Comment: You know that `validate` is not valid HTML, right? Ironic isn't it? `data-validate` is legal, but you would access it's value with `element.dataset.validate`.

Comment: My teacher told me to do it like that. Thanks i'll try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your code to start with.

Giving a `form` a `name` isn't wrong, but it's not beneficial. The `name` attribute is for fields inside of the form that need to submit their values as `name/value` pairs. The `form` itself won't be doing that. If you want to be able to identify a `form` from JavaScript, you can give it an `id` and use `.getElementById()`, or use **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** to use a CSS selector to find it.

As I mentioned in the comments, `validate` isn't a valid HTML attribute. `data-validate` is legal (it is a **[`data-` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)**), but you would access it's value with **[`element.dataset.validate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)**.

Next, event handling functions will always be passed a reference to the event object they are handling, it's good practice to set up an argument to capture it by name. By doing this, you don't need to worry about returning `true` or `false` from your function, you can just cancel or not cancel the event.

Next, don't use inline HTML event attributes (i.e. `onsubmit`). This is a 20+ year old ancient technique that we used before we had standards and unfortunately, because it is so ubiquitous, it just won't die the quick death it should. There are **[many reasons not to set up events this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** and instead use modern standards.

Next, the self-terminating syntax of `<someTag />` is a syntax known as XHTML. And, without going into great detail is another syntax that you should not adopt. **[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)** for a full explanation.

`.getElementsByTagName()` returns what's called a "live" node list and there are only certain use cases for its use because of the performance impact it has on the code. Instead, you should be using **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to find groups of elements.

Lastly, `table` elements should not be used for page layout. They should only be used to display tabular data. There are performance reasons for this, but also semantic reasons.

Frankly, your instructor should know better than to teach these out-of-date and non-best-practice techniques. And, I seriously mean it when I say that you should bring these things to his/her attention. By the way, I have been a corporate IT trainer for over 25 years - - I fully understand how to teach this stuff.

---

Now, as to your specific issue. It really just boils down to your logic not being applied correctly. You are testing to see what message to use for an empty field (based on the value stored in the `validate` attribute) and setting that message, but you didn't actually put any logic in to see if the field was actually empty. Those tests need to be adjusted.

Then, once you know that there is a value in the field, you have two separate `if` statements, one to test for too little characters and another for too many. Those should be combined into one `if` statement with an `else if` to cover both possibilities.

Just to pick up on my earlier comment about event handlers always receiving a reference to the event they are handling. With forms, we just need to assume, by default, that everything in the form is valid. Then, when any of our validation tests fail, we can set a validation "flag" to false and then at the end of the function, if the flag is `false`, we just cancel the event. If not, we don't need to do anything at all - - we just let the form submit like it was going to before we got involed.

Here's an updated version with the items above addressed and the logic reworked. See the inline comments for details:

```js
// Do all your JavaScript work separately from HTML - - no onXyz!
document.getElementById("f1").addEventListener("submit", validate);
var user = document.getElementById("userName");  // Don't name anything "name"
var nameLocation = document.getElementById("namelocation");

// This is the better way to get all the input elements inside the form, but not the submit button
let fields = document.querySelectorAll("#f1 input:not([type='submit'])");

// Event handling functions will always be passed a reference to the 
// event object they are handling, it's good practice to set up an
// argument to capture it by name
function validate(evt) {

  nameLocation.textContent = ""; // Reset the status message 

  var attribute = [];
  for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      attribute.push(fields[i].dataset.validate.split('|'));
  }

  var emptyName = attribute[0][0];
  
  var userName = user.value.trim(); // trim off any leading or tailing spaces
  var nameLength = userName.length;
  
  // Assume the form is valid by default. We only really care when the data is invalid.
  var valid = true;  

  // CHECK NAME
  
  // "empty-allowed" is not even one of the possibilities?
  
  // You need to also be checking to see if the user didn't enter anything. Otherwise,
  // what's the point of caring about this scenario?
  if (nameLength === 0 && emptyName == "empty-allowd") {
    // Don't use .innerHTML when the text you are working with doesn't contain any HTML
    // It's wasteful in terms of performance and it can open up security holes. Instead,
    // use .textContent.
    nameLocation.textContent = "ok";
  }
  
  if (nameLength === 0 && emptyName == "empty-not-allowd") {
    // There's no need to write another if statement to check for emptyName == 1, when 
    // this if has already determined that it is.   
    nameLocation.textContent = "Required.";
    valid = false;
  }
  
  if (nameLength > 0 && nameLength < attribute[0][1]) {
    nameLocation.textContent = "Name not shorter than" + " " + attribute[0][1] + " " + "characters.";
    valid = false;
  } else if (nameLength > attribute[0][2]) {
    nameLocation.textContent = "Name not longer than" + " " + attribute[0][2] + " " + "characters.";
    valid = false;
  }
  
  // If valid == false, cancel the form's submit event, otherwise don't
  !valid ? evt.preventDefault() : null;
}
```

```css
.error { color:red; }
```

```html
<!-- Forms shouldn't get a name attribute since they, themselves don't hold any data.
     An id is fine to identify it in JavaScript later. Also, don't use inline HTML 
     event attributes (onsubmit). Do you scripting separately from HTML. -->
<form id="f1" action="" method="/">
  <!-- Don't use tables for layout! Also, don't ever name anything "name". "name"
       is a property of the Global window object and you will run into trouble 
       by using it. -->
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" data-validate="empty-not-allowd|5|20">
    <!-- Avoid inine styles when possible. Break your CSS out into separate stylesheeets. -->
    <span id="namelocation" class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
        <input type="submit" value="register">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you want the console to return true only when everything was filled in correctly. However looking at the last block of your code:

```
  if (namelength > attribute[0][2]) {
    document.getElementById("namelocation").innerHTML = "Name not longer than" + " " + attribute[0][2] + " " + "characters.";
    status = false;
  } else {
    status = true;
    console.log(status);
    alert(status);
  }
```

This if else statement does the following (in psuedocode):

```
if namelength > 20 return false else return true
```

So this is already causing a problem. I didn't look into the rest of your code but I would advise you to test block by block to debug properly.