# Hide element on uncheck

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox pre-selected saying "Use profile address" and address is showing below.

Now what I want is if a customer unchecks the checkbox the pre-shown address gets hidden and a new input saying add different address appears.

I tried to do this using this **JS** trick. But couldn't achieve what I wanted. Can someone help?

```js
    $('#address-checked').change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#address-sh').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $('#address-sh').fadeOut('slow');
        }                   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="address-checked" checked="checked" class="mb-3">
    <label class="car-list-step-equipment-label">Use profile address</label>
    <address> 9 Longacre Road<br />London, GB, E17 4DT</address>
    <div id="address-sh">
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and a new input saying add different address appears.

Add this new input and toggle the display basing on the check/uncheck performed by the user:

```js
$('#address-checked').change(function() {
  $('#address-sh').toggle(!this.checked);
  $('address').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="address-checked" checked="checked" class="mb-3">
<label class="car-list-step-equipment-label">Use profile address</label>
<address>9 Longacre Road<br />London, GB, E17 4DT</address>
<div id="address-sh" style="display: none">
  Enter new address: <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try this @Ibadullah

Comment: Sir even on this the input field is visible on page load. By default I want the input field to be hidden and it should appear on uncheck.

Comment: Updater sir try it now

Answer (score 2):

You were simply hiding/showing the wrong HTML element. Changing the selector to just the `address` element fixes the issue. But, going a bit further, if you initialize the textbox and its label so that they are hidden at the start, then you don't need an `if/else` statement at all. You can just toggle the address and the textbox when the checkbox gets checked.

```js
$('#address-checked').on("change", function(){
  // You don't need and if/then here. Just toggle the visibility
  $('address').toggle('slow');
  $('.hidden').toggle('slow');              
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="address-checked" checked="checked" class="mb-3">
<label class="car-list-step-equipment-label">Use profile address</label>
<address>
  9 Longacre Road<br>
  London, GB, E17 4DT
</address>
<div id="address-sh" class="hidden">
  <label>Enter new address: <input type="text"></label>
</div>
```

Additionally, JQuery no longer recommends the use of shortcut event methods, such as `change`. Instead, the recommend the `on()` method, that you pass the event name to.

Lastly (FYI), don't self-terminate your HTML tags. That's a left over syntax from the days of XHTML and really serves no purpose today. In fact, using that syntax can actually introduce bugs into your code. [Read this for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)

Comment: With this, you solved half of the issue. The address gets perfectly hidden when unselected.

Now the second part is, by default the input field below address is hidden and it prevails with the same uncheck with which the address is fading away.

Comment: How to eliminate this slowing effect, sir?

Comment: Which self-terminating tag you're talking about?

Comment: @IbadullahKhan Your `<br />` and `<input />` tags.

Comment: So if you want to break a line what is an alternate code to <br />. I don't think so there's one in HTML 5?

Comment: It's just `<br>` and `<input>`. The trailing slash at the end of the tag does nothing. Please read the link I posted that describes this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have given id to input type text div and you are trying address label

```js
$('#address-checked').change(function(){
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('#address').fadeIn('slow');
   $('#address-sh').fadeOut('slow');
 } else {
 $('#address').fadeOut('slow');
   $('#address-sh').fadeIn('slow');
  }                   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="address-checked" checked="checked">
 <label class="car-list-step-equipment-label">Use profile address</label>
          <address id="address">
            9 Longacre Road<br />
            London, GB, E17 4DT
          </address>
          
          <div id="address-sh" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" />
          </div>
```