# How to put an id inside of an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sum

I made a code to get user input and add items to a list. Im now trying to add a button that racks the sum of all the numbers in a list and displays it when a button is clicked. Right now the code displays an alert when the button is clicked, but does not display the sum.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <input type='text' id='input' />
  <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

  <ul id='list'>
    <li> <b>Topics</b></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h3>
    
  <!--- <button id="sum">0 </button> --->
    
   <button onclick="reply_click(this.id)">Click Here To See The Sum</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script> 
    
  </h3>

</body>
  
<script>
  var sum = 0;

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = text;
  sum += parseInt(text);
  
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
  
  function sumvar() {
    alert("The sum of your numbers are ");
  }
  </script>
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: Did you debug your code in the browser?

Comment: You know your code will always generate errors since you never created the HTML element with id="sum"...

Comment: Between both answers bellow, you should have your answer, one tells you about a missing HTML element, the other about why your alert was empty.

Comment: You've got a lot of issues with your code in general. It looks like you are learning from a resource that still shows how we did things 25 years ago (seriously). See my answer below for a comprehensive explanation of the changes you should make.

Answer (score 2):

you havent an element whit id sum try to anable it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <input type='text' id='input' />
  <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

  <ul id='list'>
    <li> <b>Topics</b></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h3>
    
  <span id="sum">0 </span>
    
   <button onclick="sumvar()">Click Here To See The Sum</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script> 
    
  </h3>

</body>
  
<script>
  var sum = 0;

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = text;
  sum += parseInt(text);
  
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
  
  function sumvar() {
    alert("The sum of your numbers are "+document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML);
  }
  </script>
  
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks how to get the `id` of the clicked element, but your explanation asks how to get the sum of the items added to the list. I'll answer the how to get the `id` question below, but the final answer shows how to get the sum.

- First, don't use inline HTML event attributes (i.e. `onclick`).
  [Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)
- Next, if the element doesn't have an `id`, then there's nothing to
  get.
- Just use `this` to refer to the element that caught the
  event.

**Now, you've got some other issues to correct as well...**

- "Topics" shouldn't be in the list, it should be a title above it.
- Don't use an HTML tag because of the way it formats its content (i.e.
  `<h3>`). Use CSS for all formatting. HTML is for describing what the
  content is.
- Nothing is allowed after `</body>` except `</html>` so move that
  `<script>` you have there to just prior to the `</body>`, which will
  then place it just after the `</script>` you have for the button
  `click` code. Given that the two `<script>` elements will then be
  right next to each other, just combine them into a single `<script>`.
- `type="text/javascript"` hasn't been necessary for years on
  `<script>` elements.
- `.innerHTML` has performance and security implications, so don't use
  it when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML, use
  `.textContent` instead and also use `.textContent` instead of
  `.innerText`, which is non-standard.
- Your code refers to an element with an `id` of `sum`, but you don't
  have that in your code.
- [Don't use self-terminating tags.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597) It buys you nothing and adds
  confusion.

```css
.title { font-weight:bold; margin-top:1em; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <input type='number' id='input'> <!-- You only want numbers so use a number input -->
  <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' disabled="disabled">

  <div class="title">Topics</div>
  <ul id='list'></ul> 
  <button id="something">Click Here To See The Sum</button>

  <script>
    // Get references to the elements you'll use repeatedly:
    let list = document.getElementById("list");;
    let btn = document.getElementById("something");
    let input = document.getElementById("input");
    let add = document.getElementById("add");
    
    var sum = 0;
    
    // Set up events in JavaScript, not HTML:
    input.addEventListener("input", enableDisable);
    btn.addEventListener("click", sumvar);

    add.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.textContent = input.value;
      sum += +input.value; // The prepended + converts the string to a number
      list.appendChild(li);
      input.value = "";  // Clear out the input
      add.disabled = "disabled";
    });
   
    function enableDisable(){
      // Disable/Enable the Add button depending on if there is input to add
      if(this.value === ""){
        add.disabled = "disabled";
      } else {
        add.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    }
    function sumvar() {
      alert("The sum of your numbers is: " + sum);
    }
  </script>   


</body>
  

  
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the correct id.

You can set the sum into a data attribut on your button. And show the value on the click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <input type='text' id='input' />
  <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

  <ul id='list'>
    <li> <b>Topics</b></li>
  </ul>

  <h3>

    <button id="sum" onclick="reply_click(this.dataset.sum)" data-sum="">Click Here To See The Sum</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function reply_click(sum) {
        alert(sum);
      }
    </script>

  </h3>

</body>

<script>
  var sum = 0;

  document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = text;
    if (parseInt(text) == text) {
      sum += parseInt(text);
    }

    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    document.getElementById("sum").dataset.sum = sum;
  }

  function sumvar() {
    alert("The sum of your numbers are ");
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Note: when you addition to make your sum, don't forget to check if you have an number in input.