# Cant Get Answer Back In answer Box NAN is being shown

Tags: javascript, html

it does not returns prpoer answer it returnes NAN in Answer

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function pro(n,p)
    {
    var number=parseInt(n); 
    var powe=parseInt(p); 
    for(var i=1;i<powe;i++)
    {
     number*=number;
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").value=number;
    } 
    </script>
    </head>

<body> 
<form name="F" > 
Enter Number <input type="text" name="num" id="num"/> 
Enter Power <select name="powe" id="powe"> 
  <option value="2" >square</option> 
  <option value="3" >cube</option> 
</select> 
Answer<input type="text" name="Answer" id="answer" /> 
<input type="button" onClick="pro(num,powe)" value="Calculate" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never use the comments to add code to your question. Just edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this: `onClick="pro(num,powe)"`. Instead of the values for `num` and `powe` being gotten from the input elements and passed into the `pro` function, the actual element references (which are not numbers) are being passed.

To solve this problem, you'll need to get the `value`s of the elements. But, before you just make a quick edit to your code, [don't use inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) (`onclick`) in the first place. Instead, separate your JavaScript from your HTML and set up event handlers using modern standards with `.addEventListener()` as shown below.

Also (FYI):

- Since you aren't actually submitting form data anywhere, you don't
  need a `<form>` element.
- It's not necessary to use `parseInt` with `p.value` because that
  value is coming from your `select` and you've already set those at
  whole numbers.
- [Don't bother with self-terminating tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597) (`<input />`) as you
  gain nothing from using them.
- If you are expecting only numeric input, it's better to use `input
  type=number` which restricts the user input to numbers. Making this change also saves you from worrying about `parseInt` on the input number being misinterpreted as other bases than 10.
- Since you don't want the user to be able to change the result of the
  operation, it's better to display it in a non-editable element, like
  a `span`.
- It's a good idea to move your `<script>` element to just before the
  closing `body` tag because, by the time the parser reaches that
  point, all your HTML elements will have been parsed into memory.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body> 
     <div>    
       Enter Number <input type="number" name="num" id="num"> 
     </div>
     <div>
       Enter Power 
       <select name="powe" id="powe"> 
         <option value="2">square</option> 
         <option value="3">cube</option> 
       </select> 
     </div>
     <div>
       Answer <span id="answer"></span>
     </div>
     <div>
       <input type="button" value="Calculate">
     </div>
  <script>
  
    // Get references to the inputs, the answer container and the button
    let inputNum = document.getElementById("num");
    let power = document.getElementById("powe");
    let answer = document.getElementById("answer");
    let btn = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");
    
    // Set up the click event handler for the button
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      // Now you need to get the input values and pass them 
      // to the function that will act with them
      pro(inputNum.value, power.value);
    });
    
    function pro(n,p) {
      var number = parseInt(n); 
      for(var i = 1; i < p; i++) {
        number *= number;
      }
      answer.textContent = number;
    } 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = number
```