# Temp Conversion for Java

Tags: javascript, html

Link a javascript function to read in the input textbox and radio button, and output the results into the appropriate area. The program should use 'alert' to print out a message if temperature is not numeric, or if a radio button is not selected.

I can not get the java to calculate the conversions when I submit them.

```
//html   
<div id = "input">
<form method = "post" action = "tempcon.php" name = "form1">

Temperature: <input type = "text" name = "temp"> <br />

<input type = "radio" name = "temp1" value = "Fahrenheit"> Convert to 
Fahrenheit 

<br />

<input type = "radio" name = "temp1" value = "Celcius"> Convert to 
Celcius 

<br />

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Calculate!">



//java

window.addEventListener("load",link_events, false);
function link_events() {

document.forms["form1"]["submit"].onclick = Caculate;
}


function Calculate() {

var temp = parseFloat(document.getElementById("temp").value);

var F = document.getElementById("Fahrenheit")

var C = document.getElementById("Celcius")

if (document.getElementById("Celcius").checked){

    alert("Celcius");

    document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML = num+"Celcius," +

      (Math.round(num*9/5)+32)+"Fahrenheit";
}
else if (document.getElementById("Fahrenheit").checked){

    alert("Fahrenheit");

    document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML = num+"Fahrenheit," +

      (Math.round(num-32)*5/9)+"Celcius";

}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since this form is not actually submitting data anywhere, a `submit` button is not what you want. You just want a regular `button`.

Next, you've misspelled the function name on this line:

```
document.forms["form1"]["submit"].onclick = Caculate; // << Should be: Calculate
```

Now, you've also used `.addEventListener` to set up a callback which then sets up the actual callback (above). This is a wasted step. Just set up the button click.

You're trying to get references to elements with `.getElementById()`, when you haven't given those elements an `id`. They may have a `value` or a `name` with that string, but no `id`.

See the additional comments inline below:

```js
// Get a reference to the "button" (not submit button) that will trigger the 
// function and set up a click (not submit) event handler for it:
document.querySelector("input[type='button']").addEventListener("click", Calculate);

function Calculate() {
  var temp = parseFloat(document.getElementById("temp").value);
  if(isNaN(temp)){
    alert("You must enter a number!")
    return false;
  }
   
  // You don't need a reference to each radio button. Since they are mutually
  // exclusive, you just need to get the value of the one that is checked.
  var checkedButton = document.querySelector("input[name='FC']:checked");
  
  if(checkedButton) {
    var unit = checkedButton.value;
    alert(unit);
  } else {
    alert("You must make a selection!");
    return false;
  }  
  
  // If we've gotten this far, then there is a unit and a number
  var convertedValue = null;
 
  // You don't need to build up the entire output string twice. Just do the math.
  if(unit === "Farenheight"){
    convertedValue =  Math.round(temp -32) * 5/9;
  } else {
    convertedValue = Math.round(temp * 9/5) + 32;
  }
  
  // Then build the final message.
  // Don't use innerHTML when the string doesn't have any HTML, use .textContext:
  document.getElementById("results").textContent = convertedValue + " " + unit;
}
```

```html
<form method = "post" action = "tempcon.php" name = "form1">
  Temperature: <input type="text" id="temp" name="temp"> <br>
  <input type = "radio" name = "FC" value = "Farenheight"> Convert to Fahrenheit<br>
  <input type="radio" name="FC" value="Celcius"> Convert to Celcius<br>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculate!">
</form>
<div id = "results"></div>
```

**Also: [Don't use self-terminating tag syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it a lot better now with how you explained it.