# Displaying data outside <form>

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In advance, I say I'm a beginner. I have a problem. I want to display information from inputs but they show only for a second and disappear.

I know why: because I use `<form>`.

I use `<form>` because I need a button to reset the form. So, at the moment, with , the button reset works, but to display information doesn't. I tried to use another block "section" for instance and here, display button worked but reset doesnt -> because it work only with `<form>`.

I've tried create a function for reset inputs, I used `reset()` but it also works only with `<form>`. I found out I can use `preventDefault();` but I don't know this well and I don't know how it works exactly. May someone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show()
    {
        var button = document.getElementById("press"); 
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
        var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
        var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
        var mail_low = mail.toLowerCase(); 

        button.addEventListener("submit", function(e)
        {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = name+" "+surname+"<br/>"+mail_low+"<br/>"+"Service: "+usluga;
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    }
```

```
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name"/><br/>
    Surname: <input type="text" id="surname"/><br/>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="mail"/><br/>
    Serivce: 
    <select id="service">
        <option>naprawa komputera</option>
        <option>odzyskiwanie danych</option>
        <option>problemy z oprogramowaniem</option>
        <option>konfiguracja sieci LAN</option>
        <option>inne</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>Send copy information<br/>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Send" onclick="show()" id="press">Send</button>
</form>

<p id="info"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a `click` event of a `button` you should be setting up, it's the `submit` event of the `form`. Right now you are attempting to set the `submit` event of the `button` up, but a `button` doesn't have a `submit` event, a `form` does.

Then, simply have the event (the `form.submit`) be cancelled.

Also, [don't set up your events with inline HTML event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) (i.e. `onclick`). Use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) as shown below (and discussed in the link I shared).

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // <-- Prevents the native behavior of the event
  
  var button = document.getElementById("press"); 
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
  var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
  var mail_low = mail.toLowerCase(); 

  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = name+" "+surname+"<br/>"+mail_low+"<br/>"+"Service: "+service;  

});
```

```html
<form action="#">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br/>
    Surname: <input type="text" id="surname"><br/>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="mail"><br/>
    Serivce: 
    <select id="service">
        <option>naprawa komputera</option>
        <option>odzyskiwanie danych</option>
        <option>problemy z oprogramowaniem</option>
        <option>konfiguracja sieci LAN</option>
        <option>inne</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Send copy information<br>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" value="Send" id="press">Send</button>
</form>

<p id="info"></p>
```

But, better yet, since you aren't submitting data anywhere, you don't need a `form` element in the first place. Just manually do your reset and then you don't have to worry about submitting and cancelling.

Additionally, [don't use self-terminating tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597) (i.e. `<br/>`).

I've also reorganized your code for efficiency below.

```js
// Get your DOM references just once, not every time the event happens.
// Also, make your variables reference the elements directly, not a property
// of the element, like .value. That way, if you ever need to access the
// element for a different reason, you don't have to scan the DOM for it again.
var name = document.getElementById("userName");
var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
var mail = document.getElementById("mail");
var service = document.getElementById("service");
var output = document.getElementById("info");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");

document.getElementById("press").addEventListener("click", function (event) { 

  var mail_low = mail.value.toLowerCase(); 
  
  output.innerHTML = userName.value + " " + surname.value + "<br>" + 
                       mail_low + "<br>Service: " + service.value;  

});

reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
  name.value = "";
  surname.value = "";
  mail.value = "";
  service.value = "";
  output.innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<div>
    <!-- 
       The default type for an input is text, so: type="text" is not needed. 
       Also, since you won't be submitting data anywhere, the name attribute isn't needed either.
    -->
    Name: <input id="userName"><br>
    Surname: <input id="surname"><br>
    E-mail: <input id="mail"><br>
    Serivce: 
    <select id="service">
        <option>naprawa komputera</option>
        <option>odzyskiwanie danych</option>
        <option>problemy z oprogramowaniem</option>
        <option>konfiguracja sieci LAN</option>
        <option>inne</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Send copy information<br>
    <button id="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="button" value="Send" id="press">Send</button>
</div>

<p id="info"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. One quick question yet, What's a different way to set up events?

Comment: @Constant What do you mean a different way? Using `.addEventListener()` in your JavaScript is the proper way.

Comment: I mean, methods in JS. You said to don't set up them in HTML(in my case show() ) unless you meant something else...

Comment: @Constant Right, don't set them up in HTML. Do what I've shown in both my examples and what I talk about in the link I shared on that topic, use `.addEventListener()` in your JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way to do this would be to change the button's type from `"submit"` to `"button"`. Like so, your button will not submit the form, and hence the page will not refresh.

```
<button type="button" value="Send" onclick="show()" id="press">Send</button>
```

Comment: buttons don't have submit events. Also this listener won't be attached until the first click occurs ....which isn't practical

Comment: Will also get multiple listeners if used more than once. Just a poor structure overall