# Select All Checkbox is not working as it must be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, selectall

I am trying to implement select all checkbox and its working fine the only problem is that when I deselect the checkboxes the select all function stops working for that specific checkbox.

Note that I am using the Laravel framework so don't react on php code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#BulkSelect").click(function() {
    $('.Bulkers').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $('.Bulkers').change(function() {
    if ($(".Bulkers").length == $(".Bulkers:checked").length) {
      $("#BulkSelect").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
      $("#BulkSelect").removeAttr("checked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="BulkSelect"></th>
      <th>Hater's Name</th>
      <th>Hater's Profile Link</th>
      <th>Victim's Name</th>
      <th>Victim's Post Link</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
          <button id="btnGroupDrop3" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Action
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop3" x-placement="bottom-start">
            <form method="post" id="BulkDelete" action="{{my_route}}">
              @csrf
              <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Delete</button>
              <button type="button" onclick="BulkApprove()" class="dropdown-item">Approve</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @php($i = 0) @foreach($tables as $table)
      <tr class="gradeX">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" form="BulkDelete" class="Bulkers" value="{{$table->id}}"></td>
        <td>{{$table->column_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$table->column_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$table->column_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$table->column_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$table->column_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$table->column_name}}</td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button id="btnGroupDrop3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Action
            </button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Another possible way to go about it is to give your selectAll checkbox a data attribute that changes when the box is checked and unchecked and you can do some `if-else` statement based on the data attribute foreach checkbox

Comment: jquery 3.4.1 @PeterKA

Comment: Hi @MaazKhan, remove your php code and paste your output code as html

Comment: I would use `.prop("checked", true/false)` instead of `.attr("checked", "....")`

Comment: @PeterKA Thanks it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually since you're using `attr` when you unselect one after bulk select the Select All checkbox remains checked. Please feel free to check the docs on the difference between `attr` and `prop`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#BulkSelect").click(function() {
    $('.Bulkers').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $('.Bulkers').change(function() {
    $("#BulkSelect").prop("checked", $(".Bulkers").length === $(".Bulkers:checked").length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="BulkSelect" id="BulkSelect"/>Select All<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="Bulkers">Bulker 1<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

The problem is that with `.attr`, it only sets the attribute `checked`. However, when you click the checkboxes, the browser updates the its `.checked` property, not its `checked` attribute.

Using `.prop`, it will update the `.checked` property of a checkbox, so it will be in sync with the value change.

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#BulkSelect").click(function() {
    $('.Bulkers').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $('.Bulkers').change(function() {
    if ($(".Bulkers").length == $(".Bulkers:checked").length) {
      $("#BulkSelect").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#BulkSelect").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="BulkSelect" type="checkbox" /> Select All
<hr>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 0<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 1<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 2<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 3<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 4<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 5<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 6<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 7<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 8<br>
<input class="Bulkers" type="checkbox" /> 9<br>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597