# why wont my items show up and array keeps looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, animation

The following is the code. Some of it is from my teacher and I'm just trying to figure out why my console is looping through the array instead of animating the images onto the screen. If anyone can tell me why or how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive Catalogue App Framework</title>

    <!-- main css -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- load jquery fullscreen plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>

    <!-- load TweenMax for animation -->
    <script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <main>
        <section id="screen1">
            <img class="title" src="img/title2.png" />
            <img class="instru" src="img/instru.png">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">

            <img id="kinfe" class="element" src="img/knife.png">
            <img id="num1" src="img/num1.png">

            <img id="bow" class="element" src="img/bow.png">
            <img id="num9" src="img/num9.png">

            <img id="pads" class="element" src="img/pads.png">
            <img id="num2" src="img/num2.png">

            <img id="canteen" class="element" src="img/canteen.png">
            <img id="num3" src="img/num3.png">

            <img id="rope" class="element" src="img/rope.png">
            <img id="num4" src="img/num4.png">

            <img id="light" class="element" src="img/light.png">
            <img id="num5" src="img/num5.png">

            <img id="goPro" class="element" src="img/goPro.png">
            <img id="num6" src="img/num6.png">

            <img id="case" class="element" src="img/case.png">
            <img id="num7" src="img/num7.png">

            <img id="arrows" class="element" src="img/arrow.png">
            <img id="num8" src="img/num8.png">

            <img id="save" class="element" src="img/save.png">

            <p class="items">
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">1.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$59.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Knife</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">2.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$19.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Foot Pads</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">3.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$15.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Canteen</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">4.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$32.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Rope</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">5.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$29.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Flashlight</font><br>

            </p>
            <p class="items1">
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">6.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$69.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">GoPro</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">7.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$129.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Bow Case</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">8.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$5.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Arrows</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">9.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$599.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">PSE Compound Bow</font><br>

            </p>
            <img class="more-info" src="images/highlight1.jpg" />
        </section>

        <section id="screen2">
            <img class="title" src="img/title2.png" />
            <img class="instru" src="img/instru.png">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">

            <img class="boot" src="img/boots.png">
            <img id="no1" src="img/num1.png">

            <img id="sock" src="img/sock.png">
            <img id="no2" src="img/num2.png">

            <img id="sock1" src="img/sock1.png">
            <img id="no3" src="img/num3.png">

            <img id="sock2" src="img/sock2.png">
            <img id="no4" src="img/num4.png">

            <img id="boot1" src="img/boots1.png">
            <img id="no5" src="img/num5.png">

            <img id="boot2" src="img/boots2.png">
            <img id="no6" src="img/num6.png">

            <img id="coat" src="img/coat.png">
            <img id="no7" src="img/num7.png">

            <img id="coat1" src="img/coat2.png">
            <img id="no8" src="img/num8.png">

            <img class="coat" src="img/coat3.png">
            <img id="no9" src="img/num9.png">

            <p class="items">
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">1.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$209.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Hi-Top Boots</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">2.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$9.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Socks</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">3.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$11.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Work Socks</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">4.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$15.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Thermal Socks</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">5.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$159.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Work Boots</font><br>

            </p>
            <p class="items1">
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">6.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">109.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Saftey Shoes</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">7.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$129.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Pilots Jacket</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">8.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$89.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Hunters Jacket</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">9.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$99.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Ski Jacket</font><br>

            </p>
            <img class="more-info" src="images/highlight2.jpg" />
        </section>
        <section id="screen3">

            <img class="title" src="img/tittle.png" />
            <img class="instru" src="img/instru.png">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">

            <img class="shirt" src="img/shirt.png">
            <img class="hat" src="img/hat.png">

            <img id="shirt1" src="img/shirt1.png">
            <img id="shirt2" src="img/shirt2.png">
            <img id="thermal" src="img/thermal.png">
            <img id="boxers" src="img/boxers.png">
            <img id="boxers1" src="img/boxers1.png">
            <img id="hat1" src="img/hat1.png">
            <img id="hat2" src="img/hat2.png">

            <p class="items">
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">1.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$209.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Hi-Top Boots</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">2.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$9.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Socks</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">3.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$11.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Work Socks</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">4.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$15.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Thermal Socks</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">5.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$159.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Work Boots</font><br>

            </p>
            <p class="items1">
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">6.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">109.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Saftey Shoes</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">7.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$129.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Pilots Jacket</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">8.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$89.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Hunters Jacket</font><br>
                <b> <font color="#CC4600">9.</font>
                   <font color="#2a436b">$99.99 -</font></b>
                <font color="#81accc">Ski Jacket</font><br>

            </p>
            <img class="more-info" src="img/screen3.png" />
        </section>
    </main>
    <!-- load scale site code for editing -->
    <script src="js/scale-site.js"></script>
    <!-- main code -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

/* jslint browser: true */
/* global $, TweenMax, Back, setTimeout, setInterval, clearTimeout, document, window */
// speed of image animation in seconds
var animationSpeed = 0.5;
// time in seconds to wait before instructions reappear
var idleWaitTime = 30;
// sets what keys will be checked
// screen is based on order (screen 1 = key 1, screen 2 = key 2, etc.)
// more info keys based on keys 4-6
var keys = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]; // keys 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
// vars
var animating = false,
    activeLift = true,
    currentScreenNum,
    idleTimer,
    waitTime,
    highlighting = false,
    highlightToggle = true,
    activeKeys = [false, false, false];
// hide all sections
$('section').hide();
// show instructions screen
function displayScreenSaver() {
    TweenMax.to('#instructions', 1, {
        opacity: 1,
        onComplete: function () {
            transitonScreenOff();
            currentScreenNum = null;
        }
    });
}
// transitions all elements off screen
function transitonScreenOff() {
    // remove elements that are not part of the loop below
    $('.title, .other').fadeOut(animationSpeed * 1000);
    // loop through all 'element' classes
    $('#screen' + currentScreenNum + ' .element').each(function (index) {
        // animate elements off screen
        // only edit property and easing
        this['move' + index] = TweenMax.to($(this), animationSpeed, {
            delay: animationSpeed + index * 0.1,
            y: -1080,
            ease: Back.easeIn,
            onComplete: function () {
                // hide element after animation
                $(this.target).hide();
                // reset positioning property values
                this.pause(0);
            }
        });
    });
}
// trigger function for image animation
function displayScreen(screenNum) {
    // output screen number to browser console
    console.log("Screen Number: " + screenNum);
    // disable interactivity during animation
    animating = true;
    // disable keys
    activeLift = false;
    // hide instructions if showing
    TweenMax.to('#instructions', 1, {
        opacity: 0
    });
    // number of elements in section
    // default set to 6.67 to delay transition when not transitioning off first
    // wait enough time for instructions to fade off (6.67 * 150 = 1000 millisecs = 1 sec)
    var numEle = 6.67;
    // checks if currentScreenNum has been set
    if (currentScreenNum) {
        // sets how many elements in section
        numEle = $('#screen' + currentScreenNum + ' .element').length;
        // transitions all images off screen
        transitonScreenOff();
    }
    // wait enough time for images to transition off
    setTimeout(function () {
        // shows active screen if hidden
        $('#screen' + screenNum).show();
        // transitions all elements with a 'element' class onto screen
        $('#screen' + screenNum + ' .element').each(function (index) {
            // sets the delay for each element
            // each one will be offset by 0.1s + the duration
            waitTime = index * 0.1 + animationSpeed;
            // resets visibility of current element
            $(this).show();
            // animate element onto screen
            // only edit property and easing
            TweenMax.from($(this), animationSpeed, {
                delay: waitTime,
                y: 1080,
                ease: Back.easeOut
            });
        });
        // show screen title
        $('#screen' + screenNum + ' .title').show();
        // transition title on after final/total wait time (delay) from above
        TweenMax.fromTo('#screen' + screenNum + ' .title', animationSpeed, {
            left: -$(this).width()
        }, {
            delay: waitTime + animationSpeed,
            left: 80,
            ease: Back.easeOut
        });
        // show instructions/other content
        $('#screen' + screenNum + ' .other').show();
        // transition instructions/other content on after final/total wait time (delay) from above
        TweenMax.fromTo('#screen' + screenNum + ' .other', animationSpeed, {
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            delay: waitTime + animationSpeed,
            opacity: 1,
            onComplete: function () {
                // enable interactivity
                animating = false;
            }
        });
    }, numEle * 150);
    // sets current screen number for use when transitioning content off the screen
    currentScreenNum = screenNum;
    // clear idle timer
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    // start idle timer
    idleTimer = setTimeout(displayScreenSaver, idleWaitTime * 1000);
}
// trigger for screen highlight overlay
function highlight(screenNum) {
    // check if hightlight is hidden or showing
    if (highlightToggle) {
        // output highlight number to browser console
        console.log("Highlight " + screenNum + " showing");
        // fade in highlight/more info
        $('#screen' + screenNum + ' .more-info').fadeIn(1000);
        // animate highlighted product to the right
        TweenMax.to('#screen' + screenNum + ' .highlight', 1, {
            delay: 0.5,
            x: "+=100"
        });
        // disables access to picking up other items
        highlighting = true;
        // runs else next time
        highlightToggle = false;
    } else {
        // output highlight number to browser console
        console.log("highlight " + screenNum + " hiding");
        // animate highlighted product back to the left
        TweenMax.to('#screen' + screenNum + ' .highlight', 1, {
            x: "-=100"
        });
        // fade out highlight/more info
        $('#screen' + screenNum + ' .more-info').delay(500).fadeOut();
        // enables access to picking up other items
        highlighting = false;
        // runs if next time
        highlightToggle = true;
    }
    // clear idle timer
    clearTimeout(idleTimer);
    // restart idle timer
    idleTimer = setTimeout(displayScreenSaver, idleWaitTime * 1000);
}
// listen for down keypress
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // sets activeKeys to true
    if (e.keyCode == keys[0]) {
        activeKeys[0] = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == keys[1]) {
        activeKeys[1] = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == keys[2]) {
        activeKeys[2] = true;
    }
    // F key - go fullscreen
    if (e.keyCode == 70) {
        $(document).fullScreen(true);
    }
};
//listen for up keypress
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // only check keys when active true
    if (activeLift) {
        if (e.keyCode == keys[0] && currentScreenNum != 1 && !highlighting) {
            displayScreen(1);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == keys[1] && currentScreenNum != 2 && !highlighting) {
            displayScreen(2);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == keys[2] && currentScreenNum != 3 && !highlighting) {
            displayScreen(3);
        }
    }
    // screen highlight overlay
    if (e.keyCode == keys[3] && currentScreenNum == 1 && !animating) {
        highlight(1);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == keys[4] && currentScreenNum == 2 && !animating) {
        highlight(2);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == keys[5] && currentScreenNum == 3 && !animating) {
        highlight(3);
    }
    // sets activeKeys to false
    if (e.keyCode == keys[0]) {
        activeKeys[0] = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == keys[1]) {
        activeKeys[1] = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == keys[2]) {
        activeKeys[2] = false;
    }
};
//loop checks for all keys active
setInterval(function () {
    if (activeKeys[0] && activeKeys[1] && activeKeys[2]) {
        activeLift = true;
    } else {
        activeLift = false;
    }
}, 10);
//loop just to check activeKeys in console
setInterval(function () {
    console.log(activeKeys);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but your teaching is teaching you incorrect HTML. The `font` tag is deprecated and the `b` tag is really never used. All styling/formatting should be done with CSS. Additionally, `img` elements must include an `alt` attribute, otherwise they are not valid. And finally, [self-terminating elements should really not be used in 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597). (...cont...)

Comment: It's clear that your teacher is simply showing you code that they saw somewhere else that seems "to work", but is actually wrong. You should inform your teacher that they are teaching you incorrectly, and if this is a course you are paying for, demand your money back because what you are being taught is NOT how HTML is written. Lastly, your teacher should not be teaching you a JavaScript library (JQuery) until AFTER you have a solid grasp of JavaScript.

Comment: the font tags are my own it was a quick was to get my colors to change and etc. I am more looking to get the img to show up and they arent