# How do I make form submit only if required fields have input?

Tags: javascript

I was able to get this code to work before I put an alert button, but I need to give the user some sort of notification the form has been submitted (although not actually needing to submit anywhere). The email, phone and name fields are required but with the alert I have right now, it is giving the "submission received" alert even if required fields are empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/restaurantStyles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
const name = textField.checkValidity();
const email = emailField.checkValidity();
const phone = telField.checkValidity();


function submitAlert() {
  alert("Thank you for your feedback. Your form has been submitted.");
}
</script>

  <style>
    form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      align-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      width: 35%;
    }


      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">

                <header>
                  <h1 class="display-1">Burger Shack</h1>
                  </header>
                  <p class="lead"> New location in Rice Village coming April 2020!</p>
        </div>


      <nav>
        <hr />
        <p><a class="btn" href="index.html"> <img src="images/homeIcon.png" alt="Home Icon"></a>
          <a class="btn" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
          <a class="btn" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <hr />


<div class="container">
        <form name="contactForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" class="text-center border border-light">
          <div class="form-group row">
          <label for "Name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><b>Name:</b></label>
<div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" required> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
          <label for "Email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><b>Email:</b></label>
<div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" required> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
          <label for "Phone" class="col-md-2 col-form-label"><b>Phone:</b></label>
<div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="Phone" class="form-control" minlength=10 maxlength=10 required> </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
          <label for "inquiry" class="col-form-label"><b>Reason for Inquiry:</b></label>
<div class="col">
          <select name="Reasons" id="inquiry" class="form-control">
            <option value="CateringDefault">Catering</option>
            <option value="PrivateParty">Private Party</option>
            <option value="Feedback">Feedback </option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select></div></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
<label for "info" id="info" class="col-form-label"><b>Aditional Information:</b></label>
  <div class="col">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="txtArea"></textarea></div></div>
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for "customer" class="col-form-label">Have you been to the restaurant?</label>
<div class="col">
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="NO" class="form-check-input" checked />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label></div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="yes" name="answer" value="YES" class="form-check-input" />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
</div></div>
<div class="form-group row">
<label for"choices" class="col-form-label">Best days to contact you:</label>
<div class="col">
<div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="M">M </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="M" name="choices" value="monday" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="T">T </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="T" name="choices" value="tuesday" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="W">W </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="W" name="choices" value="wednesday" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Th">Th </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Th" name="choices" value="thursday" class="form-check-input">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="F">F</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="F" name="choices" value="friday" class="form-check-input">

</div></div>
</div> </div>
<div class="row">

            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitAlert();">Submit</button>
</div>
        </form>
      </container>




</div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

<footer>
  <hr />
  <p> 305 Gray Street, Houston, TX, 77004 <br />
    713-555-6752</p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `checkValidity()` do?

Comment: Where are you validation scripts at ?

Comment: I meant to take checkValidity() out and I thought I validated the inputs in the actual code for the form. For instance, it will notify me that I need to enter name, etc if that is not filled out (without my submitAlert() function.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `checkValidity` on each field and doing it immediately when the page loads, check the `form`'s validity during the form's `submit` event. Do not do it on the submit `button`'s `click` event. If it's valid, do nothing and let the `submit` event continue and do its thing. If it's not, cancel the event using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

**NOTES:**

Place your `script` elements near the end of the code, just before the `</body>` tag so that by the time the browser gets to that point, all of the page HTML will have been parsed into memory and is accessible.

- [Do not set up events using inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), such as
  `onclick` or `onsubmit`. Do all event binding in a separate
  JavaScript section.
- The `<footer>` element must be placed within the `<body>` element.
- [Don't use self-terminating tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597), like `<br />` or `<hr />`.
- The `<b>` element shouldn't be used just for visual styling. Use CSS instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/restaurantStyles.css" />
    <style>
      form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        align-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        width: 35%;
      }
      label { font-weight:bold; } /* Don't use <b>. Formatting is done with CSS */
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
           <header>
             <h1 class="display-1">Burger Shack</h1>
           </header>
           <p class="lead"> New location in Rice Village coming April 2020!</p>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <hr>
          <p>
            <a class="btn" href="index.html"> <img src="images/homeIcon.png" alt="Home Icon"></a>
            <a class="btn" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
            <a class="btn" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
        <form name="contactForm" method="post" class="text-center border border-light">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for "Name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" required> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for "Email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" required> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for "Phone" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Phone:</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="Phone" class="form-control" minlength=10 maxlength=10 required> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for "inquiry" class="col-form-label">Reason for Inquiry:</label>
              <div class="col">
                <select name="Reasons" id="inquiry" class="form-control">
                  <option value="CateringDefault">Catering</option>
                  <option value="PrivateParty">Private Party</option>
                  <option value="Feedback">Feedback </option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for "info" id="info" class="col-form-label">Aditional Information:</label>
              <div class="col">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="txtArea"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for "customer" class="col-form-label">Have you been to the restaurant?</label>
              <div class="col">
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="NO" class="form-check-input" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="yes" name="answer" value="YES" class="form-check-input">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for"choices" class="col-form-label">Best days to contact you:</label>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="M">M </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="M" name="choices" value="monday" class="form-check-input">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="T">T </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="T" name="choices" value="tuesday" class="form-check-input">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="W">W </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="W" name="choices" value="wednesday" class="form-check-input">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="Th">Th </label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="Th" name="choices" value="thursday" class="form-check-input">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="F">F</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="F" name="choices" value="friday" class="form-check-input">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <!-- A footer must be inside of the body -->
      <footer>
        <hr>
        <p> 305 Gray Street, Houston, TX, 77004 <br>713-555-6752</p>
      </footer>
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        // Do you event binding in JavaScript, not with inline HTML event attributes like onsubmit
        document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", submitAlert);

        // All event callbacks will automatically get the event passed to them
        function submitAlert(event) {
          // Since the form element is what raised the event, "this" will refer to it
          if(this.checkValidity()){
            alert("Thank you for your feedback. Your form has been submitted.");
          } else {
            event.preventDefault(); // Stop the submit event.
          }
        }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a id for the inputs. Second:

```
function submitAlert() {
 if (('.contact-form').find('input[type=text],select')) {
  alert("Thank you for your feedback. Your form has been submitted.");
 }
}
```

See if the inpunts are sending a value.

Comment: While `id`'s can work, it is generally better to not add `id`'s and instead access DOM elements using other means (class, location, other selector). ID based solutions are brittle, hard to support and scale.

Comment: Scott, you're right! Thanks for add it to my answer!

Comment: this is not returning my alert