# How to create linebreaks after joining strings from an array and rendering it inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have the following array:

```
results = ["Dog","Cat","Fish","Parrot"];
```

I join it using the `.join` method like so:

```
var finalResult=results.join("\n");
```

I have a `div`:

```
Validation Result:<div id="result"></div>
```

I then try to render it inside a `div` like so:

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById('result').textContent = finalResult;
```

This just ends up being rendered with a space between each word:

> Dog Cat Fish Parrot

I want it to paste each string on a new line like so:

Dog

Cat

Fish

Parrot

I can't seem to be able to achieve this. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: The issue with your attempt was the usage of `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.  `textContent` is, as it suggest, going to be interpreted as just text

Comment: var finalResult=results.join("<br>");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `<br>` instead of `\n` will solve your issue.

Maybe you can try as the following:

```js
const results = ["Dog","Cat","Fish","Parrot"];
const div = document.getElementById('elements');
div.innerHTML = results.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="elements"></div>
```

Suggested articles to read:

1. [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
2. [`<br>`: The Line Break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

I hope that helps!

Comment: [Don't use self-terminating tags.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @norbitrial is great and solves the issue. I'm hoping it's accepted as the correct solution, because it is.

The solution below is an alternative, which allows the use of the `\n` as a line break, and `textContent` property. The trick is to use a `<pre>` element.

```js
results = ["Dog", "Cat", "Fish", "Parrot"];
const finalResult = results.join("\n");
document.getElementById('result').textContent = finalResult;
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```