# for-loop doesn't function properly

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me on my issue, it seems that my loop doesn't work. I created a random number guessing game, and I wanted to have only 5 tries. And once it hits the 5th try, it will display a message. But it seems that I was able to do it countless time.

```
function RandomNumber()
        {    
            //get value from random number textbox
            var lol=document.getElementById("guess").value;
            //get new value from user 
            var ass=document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            var maxtries=5;
            for(var i=0;i<=maxtries;i++)
            { 
                if(ass == lol)//if user guess correctly
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Correct"
                    }
                else if(ass!=lol)//if user guess wrongly
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Not correct"

                    }
                else if (i==maxtries)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="No more tries"
                    }
            }
        }
```

This is my `<form>` codes

```
<td style="text-align:center">
            Lowest number: 
            <input id="digit" type="text" name="lowestnumber" onchange="validate()"><br/>
            <br/><span id="numbers"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">
            Highest number:
            <input id="digit1" type="text" name="highestnumber" onchange="validate()"><br/>
            <br/><span id="numbers1"></span>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">
            <br/><input id="rand" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="Random()" disabled><br/>
            <input id="guess" type="text" value="Random Number Generator">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center">
            <br/>Enter your number<br/>
            <input id="textbox" type="text"><br/>
            <input id="guessing" type="button" value="Random" onclick="RandomNumber()"><br/>
            <br/><span id="correct"></span>
            </td>
```

Comment: neither `ass` nor `lol` change inside the loop. Every iteration of the loop will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: This loop doesn't make sense, as there is no way for a user to enter anything while the loop is running.

Comment: Where did you called the function RandomNumber()

Comment: You might want to look into basic recursion for this scenario, as @UnholySheep says, there is no way to enter any info after the loop has started.

Comment: @UnholySheep there's a textbox, sorry that I didn't put it in, gonna edit the code.

Comment: The loop actually runs 6 times. Change `i<=maxtries` to `i<maxtries`.

Comment: `else if (i==maxtries)` never gets reached, since either `ass` equals `lol` or not. You might want to check for `maxtries` first or separately.

Comment: @ScottMarcus even if I try to guess the number 6 times, it still doesn't show the correct error message

Comment: @NgLengPoh Your problem is the input never changed after you entered the for loop. Don’t you see that?

Comment: @Lain how can I get ( i==maxtries ) to be called

Comment: Move it to the start of the condition chain, before comparing `ass` to `lol`.

Comment: @NgLengPoh I suggest you to draw a program flow diagram to analyze first. Every time the program will run the same condition branch, bro.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems here. The first and biggest (maybe) is that your loop counts down right away and doesn't give the guesser a chance to make another guess. The second problem is that the 3rd `if` statement that checks for the number of guesses can never be reached. I have refactored this check to the beginning on the function.

You should call `RandomNumber` when the user submits a new guess

You can fix this like:

```
function RandomNumber()
        {
        if (!this.guesses) {
          this.guesses = 1;
        } else {
          this.guesses++;
          if (this.guesses > 5) {
            document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="No more tries";
            return; // max guesses exceeded
          }
        }    
            //get value from random number textbox
            var lol=document.getElementById("guess").value;
            //get new value from user 
            var ass=document.getElementById("textbox").value;
                if(ass == lol)//if user guess correctly
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Correct"
                    }
                else if(ass!=lol)//if user guess wrongly
                    {
                        document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML="Not correct"

                    }
        }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it won't even allow me to generate a random number

Comment: It does work, but how does it work? I don't understand the functionality of this, what if you were to use a while or for loop?

Comment: setting `this.guesses` sets a variable that is maintained by the function (it enters a name-value pair in the function JS Object). Then every time you enter the function (with each new guess), it increments the value. When it gets to the max number of guesses (5), it checks that you have no more guesses, and then does a quick return.

Comment: The problem with a loop (while or for) is that it doesn't give the user time to enter another guess. In the loop you were using, you were repeatedly checking *the same guess against the answer*. So basically, change in your thinking to a user-driven perspective: Not "Use a loop to allow 5 guesses", but instead "After the 5th user (guess submission) event, say no more submissions allowed"

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your loop runs 6 times in a row. What you want is no loop at all, but a simple counter that can keep track of how many guesses have been made and when the count reaches the max, the guessing is over.

**Other Notes:**

- You seem to have an excessive amount of `input` elements and since
  this is just a game and you are not actually submitting the data
  anywhere, you shouldn't be using `submit` buttons and adding `name`
  attributes to the form fields.
- You should not be using tables for page layout - - that's the job of
  CSS.
- Don't use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) when you aren't working with strings that
  contain HTML as `.innerHTML` has security and performance
  implications. Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.
- [Don't use inline HTML event attributes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) Do you JavaScript separately
  from your HTML.
- [Don't use self-terminating syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)

```js
const checkAnswer=document.getElementById("guessing");
const d1= document.getElementById("digit1");
const d2= document.getElementById("digit2");
const guess = document.getElementById("guess");
const rand = document.getElementById("rand");
const result = document.getElementById("correct");

const maxtries=5;
let count = 1;
let answer = null;

d2.addEventListener("blur", function(){
 rand.removeAttribute("disabled");
});

rand.addEventListener("click", function(){
console.log(d1.value, d2.value);
  answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (d2.value - d1.value + 1) + d1.value);;
  console.log(answer);
});
  
checkAnswer.addEventListener("click", randomNumber)
function randomNumber() { 
  if(count < maxtries){
    if(guess.value == answer){
      result.textContent="Correct";
    } else {
      result.textContent="Guess " + count + " Not correct";
    } 
    count++;      // Increase the counter
  } else {
    result.textContent="No more tries";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
 Lowest number: <input id="digit1" type="text">
                <br><span id="numbers"></span>
</div>
<div>
 Highest number: <input id="digit2" type="text">
                 <br><span id="numbers1"></span>    
</div>
<div>
  <input id="rand" type="button" value="Generate Random" disabled><br>
</div>
<div>
  Enter your number<br>
  <input id="guess" type="text"><br>
  <input id="guessing" type="button" value="Check Answer"><br>
  <span id="correct"></span>
</div>
```