# Why wont the javascript document.getElementByID.value write to my fields?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out why `document.getElementById(...).value` won't write to the text fields in the following code:

```html
</div>
    <div id="righta">
    <input type="text" name="league"  id="league" readonly onload = "calcTotal()"/>League Dues
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="fee"  id="fee" readonly onload = "calcTotal()"/>Golf Course Fees
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="total"  id="total" readonly onload = "calcTotal()" />Total for the Season
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    <p> For more information, contact the League Director</p>

    </div>



    </div>
        <script>
        function calcTotal() {
            const DUES = 6;
            const FEES = 16.50;
            const WEEKS = 12;
            var owedDues = (DUES * WEEKS);
            var owedFees = (FEES * WEEKS);
            var totalOwed = (owedDues + owedFees);
            document.getElementById('league').value = "$" + owedDues.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('fee').value = "$" + owedFees.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + totalOwed.toFixed(2);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: There is no `unload` attribute on an input element. When do you want this code to run? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes

Comment: `input` elements don't execute a `load` event. Use `input` or `change`.

Comment: Are you trying to run this code on *document* onload?

Comment: @DaveNewton seems so ...

Comment: @ScottMarcus he cannot use oninput or onchange, because he has the readonly flag set

Comment: @RandyCasburn I want the fields to populate when the page loads

Comment: And, unrelated, why use readonly input fields for any of this? If you have static data what's the point of any of this?

Comment: Also, [don't use inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), like `onXyz` and [don't bother with self-terminating XHTML syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597).

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm just adding javascript to existing HTML. I did not add the readonly.

Comment: Then just call your function from your `script` and not from events in the elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I didnt realize i needed to call onload in the script. I thought it would run automatically. This fixed my problem thank you.

Comment: You're not ***calling*** `onload`. `onload` is an attribute. Since your code is in a function, it must be "invoked" by something. You don't want or need your elements to invoke the function, you can just invoke it yourself as the first thing in your `script`. Or, you could just not have the code wrapped inside of a function in the first place and just have it be the first several lines of the script.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First: `const WEEKS = 12;` in your code, should be: `const weeks = 12;` because, below you use `var owedDues = (DUES * weeks); var owedFees = (FEES * weeks);`.

Second: Try to call the function here: `<body onload="calcTotal()>"`

Good luck ;)

Comment: This is not really the correct answer as inline HTML event attributes should not be used. It "works", but it's not really right. See my comments above.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
    function calcTotal() {
        const DUES = 6;
        const FEES = 16.50;
        const WEEKS = 12;
        var owedDues = (DUES * WEEKS);
        var owedFees = (FEES * WEEKS);
        var totalOwed = (owedDues + owedFees);
        document.getElementById('league').value = "$" + owedDues.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('fee').value = "$" + owedFees.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + totalOwed.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

This *defines* a function named `calcTotal`. You're going to need to *call* it if you want it to run. You can do this by adding `calcTotal();` as a line after your function block:

```html
<script>
    function calcTotal() {
        const DUES = 6;
        const FEES = 16.50;
        const WEEKS = 12;
        var owedDues = (DUES * WEEKS);
        var owedFees = (FEES * WEEKS);
        var totalOwed = (owedDues + owedFees);
        document.getElementById('league').value = "$" + owedDues.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('fee').value = "$" + owedFees.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + totalOwed.toFixed(2);
    }
    calcTotal(); // <------------- function call here
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to call it, and just want it to run once, you can remove the `function calcTotal() {` line, and the respective closing curly brace. Your script will then be executed whenever that part of the document gets parsed by the browser (or whenever the browser decides to run it).

```html
<script>
    const DUES = 6;
    const FEES = 16.50;
    const WEEKS = 12;
    var owedDues = (DUES * WEEKS);
    var owedFees = (FEES * WEEKS);
    var totalOwed = (owedDues + owedFees);
    document.getElementById('league').value = "$" + owedDues.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('fee').value = "$" + owedFees.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + totalOwed.toFixed(2);
</script>
```

Finally, you might want to look into "Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs)", which are functions which are called:

- Once
- As soon as possible

You place these inside a `.js` file, preferably, though it should work just as easily in HTML.

You can achieve this by wrapping your function *definition* with parentheses `(function calcTotal(){/* code here */})`, and then immediately calling it:

```js
(function calcTotal() {/* code here*/})();
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onload.asp#:%7E:text=For%20input%20elements,%20the%20onload%20attribute%20is%20only%20supported%20when%20%3Cinput%20type=%22image%22%3E)

> For input elements, the `onload` attribute is only supported when `<input type="image">`

So use `onload` on `body` tag.

```
<body onload="calcTotal()">...</body>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onload="calcTotal()">
 <div id="righta">
   <input type="text" name="league" id="league" readonly/>League Dues
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="fee" id="fee" readonly/>Golf Course Fees
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly/>Total for the Season
 </div>

  <div id="footer">
   <p> For more information, contact the League Director</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    function calcTotal() {
      const DUES = 6;
      const FEES = 16.50;
      const WEEKS = 12;
      var owedDues = (DUES * WEEKS);
      var owedFees = (FEES * WEEKS);
      var totalOwed = (owedDues + owedFees);
      document.getElementById('league').value = "$" + owedDues.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('fee').value = "$" + owedFees.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + totalOwed.toFixed(2);
     }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should avoid inline HTML events where possible. `addEventListener` would be better than using `onload=""` directly. Though you'd probably just want to use Immediately Invoked Function Expressions if you wanted to run your script once as soon as possible.

Comment: Agree, not sure why he's using, may be he's learning stuff, Just fixed his issue here!! :-)