# Prioritize a click to a blur event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If you focus the input then try to click anywhere else the link is gone, good.
But if you focus the input then try to click on the link is gone, but the link didn't work. That's not what I want, I want to be redirected. I have no idea how to achieve this.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', () => document.querySelector('a').style.display = 'none')
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Comment: What do you expect? Just remove the `blur` instruction to hide the link? Or a better way to say it is, what behavior are you trying to achieve?  Also, an `input` element does not get a closing `input` tag.

Comment: Your code is working as expected: after you focus on the input, the `a` tag will be set to "display: none". And as Scott mentioned, you don't need to close the input tag, so you could simple use: `<input type="text" />`

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Just to be clear, it's not that you don't *need* to close the `input`, it's that it's invalid to do so. An `input` element forbids content. :)

Comment: @Scott Marcus Does that apply to other self-closed tags? Like `img`?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Yes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here has nothing to do with the `blur` event. It's simply a matter of handling `click` events and based on the source of the `click`, handling it the right way.

(I've removed the `target=_blank` code and changed the links to example.com just so the example will work here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment.)

```js
// Get a reference to the search items container
const items = document.querySelector(".searchItems");

// All clicks within the document will bubble here
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){ 
  // Depending on what the source of the click was, 
  // do the appropriate thing
  if(event.target.classList.contains("search")){
    // The input was the source of the click
    items.classList.remove("hidden");  // Unhide the search items
  } else if(!event.target.classList.contains("item")){
    // Something other than the input or a link was clicked
    items.classList.add("hidden");  // Hide the search items
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search">
<div class="searchItems hidden">
  <a href="https://example.com" class="item">link</a><br>
  <a href="https://example.com" class="item">link</a><br>
  <a href="https://example.com" class="item">link</a><br>
  <a href="https://example.com" class="item">link</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use this because I want to use the blur event, I don't want to do something when the link is clicked, I want to hide the link when the blur event is triggered, the link not getting clicked is an unwanted behavior.
Ask me if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: @Hunam No, it's not clear. Right now, in your code, the link ***is*** getting hidden when the `blur` event is triggered, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Hunam I'm sorry but no, this is still not at all clear. Please don't tell us what you don't want. Focus on ***exactly*** what should happen and when. The best I can tell is that you're saying that if you click out of the input and onto the link, you should get redirected, but that is what will happen without any JavaScript at all. If you do want the link to disappear, when ***exactly*** should that happen?

Comment: My real-world usage may be better, go on https://goodgle-hunam6.cloud.okteto.net/search?q=hey, when you click on the search-bar and you want to click on a suggestion it don't work because it first hides the suggestions div.

Comment: Sorry again,

**What should happen**:
1- go to https://goodgle-hunam6.cloud.okteto.net/search?q=hey
2- focus the searchbar (by clicking on it)
3- a) when you click outside of the searchbar it hides the suggestions list (currently the `hide` function, so I could also say "when you click outside of the searchbar it executes the `hide` function")
    b) when you click on a suggestion, as it's a link, it redirects you to the destination of the link

I really hope it was clear enough.

Comment: @Hunam Ok, that's better, but it gets me back to may answer above. Your desired behavior will not utilize a `blur` event. It's simply a matter of click events. The only thing I need to do to may answer to make it function like you want is to add another click event on the `document` that hides the link. Just a moment while I update.

Comment: @Hunam See updated answer. And please, when you post in the future, don't assume that you know what the solution must use (as in your assumption that `blur` was involved with the solution here, when it really was just confusing and contributed to the problem). Be clear and concise about what should happen and when.