# Array not returning any value using console log

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a program that can shuffle the middle letters (that is, all letters except the first and last letter in the word) within words. I am trying to pull words out of a string, that is pasted into a text area, in my HTML document, and create an array out of them. From there I'll figure out how to somehow make the shuffling works --but for now my problem is as follows:

```js
    const text = document.getElementById('textfield');
    const textstring = JSON.stringify(text);
  
        document.querySelector('form.input-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(text.value);   

        var a1 = new Array();
        a1 = textstring.split(' ');
        console.log(a1);
    
    });
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head> 
                <title>omrokering af bogstaver</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body id="body">
                <form class="input-form">
                    <input id="textfield" type="text" placeholder="Paste text" />
                    <button type="submit">omrokér</button>
                </form>
                
    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="omrokering.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

I can successfully pull the code out of the form, but when I try to log the contents of the array (I have tried a lot of different ways), it prints this: (1) ['{}'] in the console log, after I've typed in the textarea. When I use this alert function:

```
if(textstring !== null){alert(null);}
```

It returns "null", so I'm assuming the array is empty, and there is a problem with pulling the string from the form into the array.

I'm very beginner, so it will be greatly appreciated if you can give me a good explanation for this along with a solution, thank you!

Comment: why are you doing this? `const textstring = JSON.stringify(text);`
Maybe you wanted to do ` `const textstring = JSON.stringify(text.value);`?

Comment: You are stringinfying an DOM element? What? `const text = document.getElementById('textfield');` <-- dom element and you do `const textstring = JSON.stringify(text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Stringifying the element is wrong and unnecessary.
- `type="text/javascript"` is also unnecessary as this is the default.
- `<input />` <--  [Don't bother with self-terminated syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)

```js
const text = document.getElementById('textfield');

document.querySelector('form.input-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(text.value);   
  var a1 = text.value.split(' ');
  console.log(a1);
});
```

```html
<form class="input-form">
  <input id="textfield" type="text" placeholder="Paste text">
  <button type="submit">omrokér</button>
</form>
<script src="omrokering.js"></script>
```

Comment: You must trim the value, otherwise the resulting array will contain elements with only white spaces. Try this `var a1 = text.value.trim().split(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `textstring` that is unnecessary and don't `stringify()` as it's already a string;
and use `text element` only which you already console.log().

```js
const text = document.getElementById('textfield');
  
document.querySelector('form.input-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(text.value);
  console.log(text.value.split(' '));
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head> 
                <title>omrokering af bogstaver</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
            <body id="body">
                <form class="input-form">
                    <input id="textfield" type="text" placeholder="Paste text" />
                    <button type="submit">omrokér</button>
                </form>
                
    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="omrokering.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```